# Automated MySQL Value Lookup

Tags: mysql, database, datagrip

I am creating a custom MySQL database for a swimming gala. The two tables relevant to this query are galaEvents and galaResults. I want to have it so that the database can read the value of eventNumber in galaResults in a record (which is restricted by a cascading foreign key from galaEvents), find a value in the same record of the galaEvents table, then return that value to the original record in the galaResults table. Does anyone have an idea about how to go about this? It would be very much appreciated.

This is an up-to-date MySQL 8.0 server, with data being accessed through the DataGrip IDE.

galaEvents schema (simplified for question):

```
eventNumber    int          not null primary key,
eventRecord    time(2)         null
```

galaResults schema (simplified for question):

```
resultId            int auto_increment primary key
eventNumber         int          not null
eventRecord         time(2)      null
```

Comment: Did you have a question. If so you could improve it by adding sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: Sample data in galaEvents:

eventNumber - 3
eventRecord - 00:00:15.07

Sample Data for galaResults:

resultId - 1 (would be auto-generated)
eventNumber - 3 (value used for lookup in galaEvents)
eventRecord - 00:00:15.07 (value retrieved via lookup, so this would not be manually typed)

Comment: There is no such thing as an auto mated look up in sql. You may be looking for a trigger which could push data on an inert to one table into another table.